# Best practices for allowing rollback of individual customers on a shared database

Tags: postgresql, rollback

Imagine having multiple customers (as an example) on a shared database, and needing a backup system so that a single customer can be rolled back without affecting the other customers. - It's not important whether the customers themselves can order the rollback or only an administrator of sorts, but for a host of reasons is having a database for each customer not an option.

Edit:
There would be a customer table, but the customer's data will be spread across many tables. Maybe because a customer can add stuff only they can access.
\Edit

How can this best be achieved?

I have considered the following options (don't mind the order):

#1
Making a regular database backup and building a mechanism that clears all relevant rows in all relevant tables and then reads the customer's data from the backup-file and insert it into the database.
This mechanism will have to be maintained as the database changes.

#2
Making a shadow-table for each relevant table.
The needed mechanism will essentially be the same as for #1, but it won't be necessary to read from an external backup-file. The mechanism and shadow-tables will have to be maintained as the database changes.
This will work better than #1 if customers need be able to order rollback autonomously.

Any option I'm missing?
Anything I should be mindful about?
Most importantly: Any best practice for doing this sort of thing?

I'm using PostgreSQL in case that includes anything that can help.

Comment: Are the data for different customers stored in a single table, in different tables, different schemas or different databases?

Comment: https://pgxn.org/dist/temporal_tables/

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Different tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mimic the transaction system of PostgreSQL:

- Every affected table has a column `visible_from` and `visible_to`, type `timestamp with time zone`.
- When you update or delete a table, set `visible_to` on the old version of the row to the current timestamp rather than actually updating or deleting it.
- When you update or insert a table, add a new row with `visible_from` set to the current timestamp.

This way you can determine the state of the table at any given point in time. Rolling back is now a matter of deleting some rows and clearing `visible_to` on others.

Periodically a job removes data with `visible_to` older than a certain grace period.

Comment: I like this. However it does present new problems with regard to primary keys, foreign keys and indexes (unique and otherwise). All of them are going to be affected by this.

Every time a row in such a temporal-table is updated either
1) Any row referencing that row will have to be updated as well
2) Foreign-keys should in these cases be omitted and when using the reference to e.g. a GUID the one with the latest visible_to should be used.
I think 2 is best.

Comment: Edit to option 2: The row for that GUID with a visible_to that is null/infinity.

Comment: Unique indexes can be solved by including "WHERE visible_to = infinity"

Comment: I agree with all your comments. Foreign keys will definitely present a problem, and you may have to do without them (or use a constraint trigger, which is not a perfect solution).